CSS Transform Animation on iOS only work correctly after home screen/locking then reopening browser
I have an element in html styled like a horizontally scrolling LED display:
<div class="led-display">
    <div class="scrolling-text" id="scrollingText"></div>
</div>

.led-display {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.scrolling-text {
    white-space: pre;
    color: rgb(255, 94, 94);
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Scoreboard';
    position: absolute;
}

.scrolling-text,
.message {
    text-shadow:
        0 0 5px #f00,
        0 0 10px #f00,
        0 0 20px #f00,
        0 0 40px #f00;
    will-change: transform;
    animation-name: scroll-left;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
            from {
                transform: translateX(100vw);
                -webkit-transform: translateX(100vw);
            }
    
            to {
                transform: translateX(-100%);
                -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
            }
        }


I am using javascript to fetch the data for the each message, add spacing between them, and calculate the duration of the animation - all within a DOMContentLoaded event listener:
fetch('/static/messages.txt')
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(data => {
            const messages = data.split('\n').filter(msg => msg.trim() !== ''); // Split lines and remove empty ones
            const scrollingText = document.getElementById('scrollingText');

            // Add a large space between each message
            const spacedMessages = messages.map(msg => msg + ' '.repeat(20)).join('');
            console.log("spaced the messages")

            // Wait for the browser to calculate the width
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                const textWidth = scrollingText.offsetWidth; // Measure the full width of the scrolling content
                const displayWidth = document.querySelector('.led-display').offsetWidth;

                // Calculate animation duration (e.g., 0.05 seconds per pixel)
                const animationDuration = (textWidth + displayWidth) / 100; // Adjust speed as needed

                // Update the CSS animation duration dynamically
                scrollingText.style.animationDuration = `${animationDuration}s`;
                const reflowTrigger = scrollingText.offsetHeight; // Read a property to trigger a reflow

                // Add precise padding to avoid long pauses
                scrollingText.style.paddingRight = `${displayWidth}px`;
            });

            scrollingText.textContent = spacedMessages;
            console.log("appended text content")
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error loading messages:', err);
            document.getElementById('scrollingText').textContent = 'Error loading messages.';
        });

The problematic behaviour that I am experiencing only on iOS devices (so far), is that the text content begins to scroll from right to left as expected, but not long into the animation, the text that has crossed over the rightmost edge into the visible display disappears, and one or two fractured pieces of the remaining text pass over the edge into the visible display and also disappear, usually after one or two of those pieces, no more of the lengthy text shows up.
The most unexpected part of the problem is that when the page is first loaded, or if it is refreshed, the problem exists; but if I swipe to go to the iphone home page and quickly come back to the browser, or if I lock the device and unlock it again, the animation plays noticeably quicker than it did before, and none of the disappearing text issues are present!
If anyone has any experience with this sort of issue I would be so grateful to hear what I could improve to fix this - thank you.
So as you may be able to tell in my shoddy javascript, I was looking to trigger this behaviour in the code, I have not had any success though and I'm not sure what the correct term is for that behaviour - AI says it is a 'reflow'.
I tried to add some code after the js to turn visibility off and on again to see if that retriggering would help but alas no:
scrollingText.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    scrollingText.offsetHeight;

    scrollingText.style.visibility = 'visible';

I added the webkit prefixes in CSS, the ones I knew did not work and I struggled to find information that seemed particularly useful.
I tried this on multiple iOS devices so I am certain this is not a CSS caching issue and i'm fairly certain this should be functional on iOS 17; i've seen other websites on my phone with this kind of element working just fine.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const multilineString = `
        Welcome to our display!
        Stay tuned for updates.
        Don't miss our special offers!
    `;

    // Split the multiline string into an array of messages and remove empty ones
    const messages = multilineString.trim().split('\n').filter(msg => msg.trim() !== '');

    const scrollingText = document.getElementById('scrollingText');

    // Add spacing between messages, but not after the last one
    const spacedMessages = messages.map((msg, index) => {
        return index < messages.length - 1 ? msg + ' '.repeat(20) : msg; // Add spaces only if not the last item
    }).join('');
    scrollingText.textContent = spacedMessages;

    // Use requestAnimationFrame to ensure the text content is fully rendered before measuring
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        const textWidth = scrollingText.scrollWidth; // Measure the full width of the scrolling content
        const displayWidth = document.querySelector('.led-display').offsetWidth;

        console.log("Measured text width:", textWidth); // Log the measured text width
        console.log("Display width:", displayWidth); // Log the display width

        // Calculate the animation duration (e.g., 0.05 seconds per pixel)
        const animationDuration = (textWidth + displayWidth) / 100; // Adjust speed as needed
        console.log("Animation Duration:", animationDuration); // Log the animation duration

        // Add precise padding to avoid long pauses
        scrollingText.style.paddingRight = `${displayWidth}px`;

        // Stop the animation and reinitialize it
        scrollingText.style.animation = 'none'; // Stop the animation
        scrollingText.offsetHeight; // Trigger a reflow (if needed)
        scrollingText.style.animation = ''; // Restart the animation

        // Prefetch the animation pipeline
        scrollingText.style.animation = 'scroll-left 0s linear infinite'; // Prefetch animation
        scrollingText.offsetWidth; // Trigger reflow

        // Add a 200ms delay before starting the animation
        setTimeout(() => {
            scrollingText.style.animation = `scroll-left ${animationDuration}s linear infinite`; // Set correct duration
            console.log("Animation initialized successfully.");
        }, 200); // 200ms delay before triggering the animation
    });
});
@keyframes scroll-left {
    from {
        transform: translateX(100vw);
        /* Start from the right edge */
    }

    to {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        /* End after the entire text has moved out of view */
    }
}

.doto-<uniquifier> {
  font-family: "Doto", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: <weight>;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variation-settings:
    "ROND" 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
 }

.led-display {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    clip-path: inset(0, 0, 0, 0);
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.scrolling-text {
    white-space: pre;
    color: rgb(255, 94, 94);
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Doto';
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    will-change: transform;
    position: absolute;
}

.scrolling-text,
.message {
    text-shadow:
        0 0 5px #f00,
        0 0 10px #f00,
        0 0 20px #f00,
        0 0 40px #f00;
    will-change: transform;
    animation-name: scroll-left;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Doto:wght@100..900&display=swap');
</style>

<div class="led-display">
    <div class="scrolling-text" id="scrollingText"></div>
</div>



I added a runnable snippet as suggested, the javascript is slightly different now as i've added a set timeout of 200ms, but I still often get the same issues as before.

I think it would be helpful if you could make a runnable snippet which shows the problem. Use <> in the editor.
